# Rails passing id to rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hey I'm trying to test my `new` action with rspec and I'm running into some trouble.

Here is the `new` action for my `scores_controller` A score is also going to be associated with a site. A `site` `has_many` `scores` and a `score` `belongs_to` a `site`

```
def new
    @score = Score.new(site: Site.find(params['site_id']))
  end
```

Here is my rspec test at the moment:

```
describe 'new' do
    with :user
    with :score
    with :site
    before do
      sign_in user
      get :new, id: site.id
    end
    it { expect(response).to have_http_status :ok }
    it { should render_template :new }
    it 'assigns a new score as @score' do
      expect(assigns(:score)).to be_a_new(Score)
    end
  end
```

And here is the error I'm getting

```
1) ScoresController new
     Failure/Error: @score = Score.new(site: Site.find(params['site_id']))

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Site with 'id'=
     # ./app/controllers/scores_controller.rb:19:in `new'
     # ./spec/controllers/scores_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I know `id: site.id` is wrong, but I can't figure out how to test it with a `site_id` I'm also really new to rails so sorry if it's super obvious.

Here is my schema if it's needed

```
create_table "scores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "value",      null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "site_id"
    t.string   "response"
  end

  add_index "scores", ["site_id"], name: "index_scores_on_site_id", using: :btree

  create_table "sites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Edit: Here is my routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                              sites#index
                   sites GET    /sites(.:format)               sites#index
                         POST   /sites(.:format)               sites#create
                new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format)           sites#new
               edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format)      sites#edit
                    site GET    /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#show
                         PATCH  /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#update
                         PUT    /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#update
                         DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)           sites#destroy
                  scores GET    /scores(.:format)              scores#index
                         POST   /scores(.:format)              scores#create
               new_score GET    /scores/new(.:format)          scores#new
              edit_score GET    /scores/:id/edit(.:format)     scores#edit
                   score GET    /scores/:id(.:format)          scores#show
                         PATCH  /scores/:id(.:format)          scores#update
                         PUT    /scores/:id(.:format)          scores#update
                         DELETE /scores/:id(.:format)          scores#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Assuming your routes are correct you need to create a site first in your test.  So my_site = Site.create!(site_attribute: attribute_value).  get :new, id: my_site.id

Comment: `with :site` already does that

Comment: What is the output of rake routes?  I am suspecting your routing could be wrong.  Also can you post your associations.

Comment: added routes and explained associations at the top of post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change this line

```
get :new, id: site.id
```

to

```
get :new, site_id: site.id
```

because in your `new` method you load a `Site` by `params[:site_id]`.

Comment: In newer versions: `get :new, params: { site_id: site.id }`